# traversing singly linked list in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

I have a simple Java question. As shown in the below code:

```
public static ListNode removeNthFromEnd(ListNode head, int n) {

        ListNode start = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode slow = start, fast = start;
        slow.next = head;

        //Move fast in front so that the gap between slow and fast becomes n
        for(int i=1; i<=n+1; i++)   {
            fast = fast.next;
        }
        //Move fast to the end, maintaining the gap
        while(fast != null) {
            slow = slow.next;
            fast = fast.next;
        }
        //Skip the desired node
        slow.next = slow.next.next;
        return start.next;
    }
```

Start, fast and slow address the same object. I don't get why  "slow = slow.next;" will not change the start object, but "slow.next = slow.next.next;" will change the start object.

Comment: Your question title doesn't really relate to what you're doing. I made the incorrect assumption that you were just trying to visit each node. Could you maybe improve it?

Comment: This also seems to scream for null pointer exceptions. You create a **start** node; which probably means that it hasn't any followers in that list. Iterating that sounds like asking for trouble.

Comment: @GhostCat except that two lines down, there's `slow.next = head;` As one line above you have `slow=fast=start`, the `slow.next=head` means 'start is initialized with the meaning of `node at index -1` and slow/fast are set to this position'. Then everything is fine and dandy **if the list contains N elements**  because the `for(int i=1; i<=n+1; i++)` cycle doesn't test against `null`.

Answer (score 2):

`slow` is a local variable, so changing its value to refer to a new instance of `ListNode` doesn't affect the original list.

However, if `slow` refers to a `ListNode` that belongs to your list, changing `slow.next` to refer to a new instance changes the state of your list.

It may be clearer if you use a setter to modify the next node :

```
slow.next = slow.next.next;
```

would be equivalent to :

```
slow.setNext(slow.next.next);
```

So if `slow` refers to a `ListNode` that belongs to your list, changing its state is changing the state of your list.